# Why didn't my questions get any attention?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions

I have a problem and asked a question ([Problem with async_read when packet length is more or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153075)) that didn't get any attention.

After a while I've checked everything again and asked another question ([First boost async_read isn't invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201815)) from a different point of view. This one is not getting any attention either. It's been a week since the first question and 4 days since the second.

- Is there a problem with its grammar? I am not a native speaker.
- Are these questions too big or too hard, making people tired of reading them?
- What's the problem with these questions?

Comment: Try to edit the questions so that they get displayed :)

Comment: @dan1st, so you suggest they are not properly explained? Why not anyone commented? I don't get any down vote on either!

Comment: No, the algorithm displays recently asked/edited questions on the main site. But please don't overdo this.

Comment: Editing a question just to pop it back up to the top of the active list is not something you should be doing. I don't work with c++ so I don't know if your questions are about popular concepts or not but sometimes questions just don't get attention if they're about things people don't normally work with. That's just how it is, we can't force people to look at them.

Comment: [Your second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201815/first-boost-async-read-isnt-invoked) is missing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *in the body of the question itself*, which raises the barrier for people to help you. They have to do a lot more work in order to understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: For both questions, but more pointedly for the second, it seems like it's not possible to answer them without reviewing quite a bit of off-site resources. That makes them not only less likely to be answered, but potential targets for down and close votes.

Comment: @toolic, I have though too, but I said "I have a problem..."